# AttributeError: SubRequest instance has no attribute 'param'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, splinter

When I run a test with parameters I should be able to access the actual test parameter thought the request's `param` attribute but instead a got this error:

```
AttributeError: SubRequest instance has no attribute 'param'
```

This seems to appear only when I use `pytest-bdd` test framework. In the following an example of my test fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=(
    {
        'driver_name': 'remote',
        'url': 'http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub',
        'browser': 'safari',
        'platform': 'MAC'
    },
    {
        'driver_name': 'remote',
        'url': 'http://x.x.x.x:4444/wd/hub',
        'browser': 'chrome',
        'platform': 'MAC'
    }
))
def browser_kwargs(request):
    """Webdriver kwargs."""
    return request.param 

@pytest.fixture
def browser(browser_kwargs):
    """Splinter webdriver"""
    return Browser(**browser_kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you post the verson of the python packages you are using?

Comment: @lapinkoira: splinter==0.7.2, pytest==2.7.0, pytest-bdd==2.6.2, pytest-django==2.8.0, Django==1.7.4, Python 2.7.6

Comment: why don't you use pytest-splinter and parametrize splinter_webdriver fixture, if you need?

Comment: @bubenkoff: Problem arises with pytest-splinter as well. I think that problem came from some request fixture redefinition but I can't figure out which plugin does that.

Comment: You could list all fixtures by command line to check the collection

Comment: I think the mentioned issue is already being fixed in pytest https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/926

Comment: I got this because I was running pytest and had a pytest fixture that was `autouse=True` which was using `request.param` while also having old unittest tests (so all of the unittest tests failed)

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to stop letting my test class inherit from `unittest2.TestCase`:

```
class ViewTestSuite(unittest2.TestCase):
    '''Raises error'''

class ViewTestSuite():
    '''No error'''
```

It seems (though I'm not sure), that in my case, the real culprit was hidden deep inside `pytest`, and seems to have been the `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError("'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'callspec'",)
```

caught [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/8a94c66e6834e060e20d3bc6691594bf4bf42153/_pytest/python.py#L1653),
causing `param` not to be set on `request` (`SubRequest` in this case).